# How do I let the user input enter a decimal number as well as just an integer?

Tags: python

How do I let the user input any type of number that they want? Here is what I tried:

```
a=0
def main():
    x = int(input("Input a number in Celsius to convert it to Fahrenheit"))
    f = (x*1.8)+(32)
    print(f, "degrees Fahrenheit")

a=a+1
while a > 0:
    main()

main()
```

Comment: Do you mean a `float`... ?

Comment: How about `float(input("..."))`?

Comment: Oh okay, thanks this really helped, I'm a beginner at python so I'm still learning the basics

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. Correct indentation is vital in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use this:

```
x = float(input('Input a number in celcius to convert it to fahrenheit'))
```

Then carry out the required calculations with `x`.

Read about basic types in python [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesnumeric.html).

Any way, your indentation as given in the question is totally wrong. Your code should not even run. And your logic for running `main()` is also absurd. It could have been something like this:

```
a=0

def main():
    x = float(input("Input a number in celcius to convert it to fahrenheit"))
    f = (x*1.8)+(32)
    print(f, "degrees fahrenheit")

while a < 10: # for taking 10 inputs and converting
    main()
    a += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the `type` of number you want you just have to try and catch

UPDATE
since raw_input stores it data as `str`, because `isinstance(x, str)` will give you `True`.

```
x = raw_input("Input a number in celcius to convert it to fahrenheit")

try:
    val = int(x) # you can also covert to float before doing your calculation
    #carry out your calculations
except ValueError:
    print("That's not an int!")
```

Comment: Nice example code. I would just point out the direction... but this is what i meant (i prefer to let people do things themselves, with a bit of help in the good direction, but that's probably personal)

Comment: That `x.isdigit()` isn't necessary, but more importantly, it won't work properly, since a string representing a number may contain non-digits. Any number may be prefixed by a negative sign `-`, and a float may also be prefixed by a `+`, it may also contain a decimal point `.` and if in scientific notation it will contain `E` or `e`.

Comment: @PM2Ring the answerer tried to re-invent the wheel here, but only to invent it a faulty wheel, no offence :)

Comment: You should test your code on a few different inputs. If you feed it a string like '3.5' it will raise `ValueError`, the `float(x)` won't get a chance to run.

Comment: Hey, @Shadowfax, it's easy to do that. :) Which is why I _always_ test code before posting it in an answer, even if I think it's simple and _should_ work correctly.

Comment: @PM 2Ring i'm sorry i didnt test, it was only to give guide to find his solution and i have also corrected myself when you pointed the error

Comment: There's no need to apologise. And thanks for fixing your code, but it still won't work correctly. FWIW, I didn't notice the second error myself when I posted that earlier comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104022/discussion-between-transformer-and-pm-2ring).